# Docker Containers Unable to Resolve DNS Names

Tags: networking, arch-linux, docker, dns

I am experiencing a persistent issue with Docker on Arch Linux where containers are unable to resolve DNS names. Containers can ping external IP addresses, indicating functional network connectivity, but fail at DNS resolution. This problem persists across all containers and is not specific to a single image. Please note that this was never an issue on this machine until yesterday. I used Docker for work every day and have never had this problem. I am on Arch Linux, so maybe a new update broke something? Note sure.

Kernel: 6.6.7-arch1-1

Docker: 24.0.7, build afdd53b4e3

I have not messed with the docker network configuration in any way at all.

Steps Taken:
Verified that containers can ping external IPs (e.g., 8.8.8.8).
Configured Docker to use Google's DNS servers in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{
    "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]
}
```

Checked iptables rules and found no obvious misconfigurations.
Removed and reinstalled Docker, including deletion of `/var/lib/docker`.
Ensured no conflicting software like VPNs or firewall rules that could interfere.

Running a container with a command like `docker run --rm busybox ping -c 4 google.com` results in `ping: bad address 'google.com'`, whereas pinging an IP directly (e.g., 8.8.8.8) works fine. `docker run --rm --dns 8.8.8.8 busybox ping -c 4 google.com` also does not work. `resolv.conf` within the containers is set to google DNS also.

`docker network inspect bridge` output appears normal.
Host machine's `/etc/resolv.conf` is set to use Google's DNS.
iptables configurations seem standard for Docker (I have never messed with them).

I'm pretty stumped here. Has anyone had a similar issue? Please let me know if any additional information would be helpful.